# how does laravel UPDATE method work

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am working on this laravel project where user can upload an avatar image. My users table does not have any column yet to store the file location. So i was testing this in phpunit following the TDD series in laracast.

After the file is uploaded successfully and moved to the desired location in the server, i called the update method on the authenticated user like below:

```
$user = auth()->user();
$user->update(['avatar_location' => 'avatars/avatar.jpg']);
```

Note that **avatar_location** is not yet there on the users table. I expected this to fail but it didn't. I tried to find out what was going on so i followed through to the *update()* method in the model class:

```
//file Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php

public function update(array $attributes = [], array $options = [])
{
    //dd($attributes);     //prints 'avatar_location"=>"avatars/avatar.jpg'
    if (! $this->exists) {
        //dd($attributes);
        return false;
    }
    return $this->fill($attributes)->save($options);
}
```

till this point the dd($attribute) prints the value that i passed to the update() method.
So i followed into the **fill()** method that is being called with the **attribute** parameter. However when i die dumped the received parameter from inside the fill() method i am not seeing the key=>value pair that i passed. Instead it was showing the other attributes of the user:

```
 /**
 * Fill the model with an array of attributes.
 *
 * @param  array  $attributes
 * @return $this
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\MassAssignmentException
 */
public function fill(array $attributes)
{
    //dd($attributes);

    //does not print 'avatar_location"=>"avatars/avatar.jpg'
    //rather, prints:
    //array:4 [
    //  "name" => "Armand Mraz"
    //  "email" => "akautzer@example.net"
    //  "password" =>         "$2y$10$h7OG9/Toh31MsyFQc8lfg.wHeQC7maP4Bh37bea.DXU//IuRuXZi."
    //  "remember_token" => "X0udISwEEM"
    ]

    $totallyGuarded = $this->totallyGuarded();

    foreach ($this->fillableFromArray($attributes) as $key => $value) {
        $key = $this->removeTableFromKey($key);

        // The developers may choose to place some attributes in the "fillable" array
        // which means only those attributes may be set through mass assignment to
        // the model, and all others will just get ignored for security reasons.
        if ($this->isFillable($key)) {
            $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
        } elseif ($totallyGuarded) {
            throw new MassAssignmentException($key);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out why?

1. can anyone please explain?
2. And why the update method is not failing even though i am trying to update a column that does not exist?

Thanks,Yeasir

Answer (score 0):

When you're updating an object, Laravel is trying to match the keys of the array of data and the list of fillable fields. All pairs of key/valye missing from the fillable fields are not considered. It's the reason why it's not failing.

You have to update the fillable field list (property $fillable) in your user model.

Have a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment).

If you add `avatar_location` in your fillable fields list and the field doesn't exist, in this case, it will throw an exception.

Comment: Ok. But at what point between the update() and fill() method in the above example is the **attributes** array changing? how?

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder Normally, avatar_location key must be there at the beginning of the fill function, and disappear after the foreach loop, which will verify fillable fields. If you add 'avatar_location' in the fillable property of your model, the value is still missing at the beginning of the fill function ?

Comment: Yes, it is still missing!! I have been scratching my head for last couple of hours trying to figure that out :(

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder There's actually no reason for the value to disappear. I thought about the updating/saving triggered events, but the value would be missing at the beginning.

The problem by putting a dump&die into the fill function, is that it's use in the constructor. So, I'm not really sure that you're dumping at the good moment. In fact, you think you're dumping while updating but I think it's while retrieving the logged user from the auth guard. Then the $attributes are not the posted data, but the session data of the logged user, without the avatar_location key/value.

Comment: @YeasirArafatMajumder Try logging instead of dumping&die, and die after treatment (https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors). Log::debug('Start fill'); Log::debug($attributes); Log::debug('End fill');

Comment: that could be it. the dd is executing when the constructor in the user model calls the fill method. I will try what you suggested and will get back. thanks!